# slickgrid validate row that is going to be added

Tags: javascript, validation, slickgrid

As in examples a new row is added when you type something into one of the cells of last row. How is it possible to add new row only after all cells in this new row are valid to the `validator` rules of columns ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working snippet. It doesn't stop row from being added but it runs all validations on a new row and forces user to enter all missing values.

First define validateRow function (ideally it should be put in SlickGrid namespace):

```
function validateRow(grid, rowIdx) {
    $.each(grid.getColumns(), function(colIdx, column) {
        // iterate through editable cells
        var item = grid.getDataItem(rowIdx);

        if (column.editor && column.validator) {
            var validationResults = column.validator(item[column.field]);
            if (!validationResults.valid) {
                // show editor
                grid.gotoCell(rowIdx, colIdx, true);

                // validate (it will fail)
                grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit();

                // stop iteration
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then invoke it in *onAddNewRow* binding func (or after adding a item to Array if you're not using DataView):

```
    grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe(function (e, args) { 
        dataView.addItem($.extend({
            id: dataView.getLength()
        }, args.item));
        validateRow(args.grid, args.grid.getActiveCell().row);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid doesn't support that.

Comment: Ok. and what about making invalid cells (after adding new row) with red background ? Maybe some workaround can help me?

Comment: In your onAddNewRow handler, you can validate all cells and provide the "invalid" CSS class for the cells in question (see https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid).